# Image does not open with python imaging library

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, python-imaging-library

I have just installed the Python imaging library and started to learn it but I cannot sem to open the image file.

```
    import Image
    im = Image.open("Desert.jpg")
    print im.format, im.size, im.mode
    im.show()
```

the image attributes are printed fine but when the image opens in windows viewer, I get the error

```
     File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pythonwin\pywin\framework\scriptutils.py" 
     ,line 325, in RunScript           
     exec codeObject in __main__.__dict__
     File "C:\Users\Hassan\Documents\imtest.py", line 2, in <module>
     im = Image.open('Desert.jpg')
     File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1952, in open
     fp = __builtin__.open(fp, "rb")
     IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'Desert.jpg'
```

I have placed the file Desert.jpg in the same directory where this script is saved.What should I do to open this file.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use an absolute path. You can get the path of the script to create that path:

```
import os.path

script_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
im = Image.open(os.path.join(script_dir, 'Desert.jpg'))
```

Otherwise, relative files (anything without an absolute path) are opened relative to the current working directory, and that depends entirely on how you started the script and your operating system defaults.

The `__file__` variable is the filename of the current module, the `os.path` calls ensure it is a full absolute path (so including the drive when on Windows, starting with a `/` on POSIX systems), from which we then take just the directory portion.

Comment: NameError: name "\__file\__" is not defined

Comment: @AnnaVopureta: in what context? `__file__` is set in *python modules*, not the interactive shell or in `cython`-generated extension modules. Some executable wrappers such as `py2exe` also don't set it on the main script. The exact work-around you need depends on where you are trying to get a filename.