# Image Open Tkinter Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm working with Tkinter and developing a program that uses a PNG image, here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk, Image

class Application:
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        self.ProgramaTOP = Frame(master)
        img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image.open("company.png"))
        self.ProgramaTOP.pack()
        self.msg = Label(self.ProgramaTOP, text="Teste Senha", foreground="#00338d", image= img)
        self.msg["font"] = ("Univers", "12", "bold")
        self.msg.pack()
        self.TesteSenha = Button(self.ProgramaTOP)
        self.TesteSenha["text"] = "Teste Senha"
        self.TesteSenha["font"] = ("Univers", "12", "bold")
        self.TesteSenha["width"] = 10
        self.TesteSenha["command"] = self.ProgramaTOP.quit
        self.TesteSenha.pack()

root = Tk()
Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

When I try to run got this error:

> File
>   "C:\Users\lucascruz\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py",
>   line 2809, in open
>       fp = builtins.open(filename, "rb") FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'company.png'

I know that is a path problem, how can I do to program open the image from the directory where my program is running?

In the future, this program will distribuited to other people, in other machines so the code need to be flexible for every machine, my idea is to create a folder with the stored images and the code acess this folder.

How can I do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Image does not open with python imaging library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17778258/image-does-not-open-with-python-imaging-library)

Comment: Try `"./company.png"`. The `./` should tell python to look in the working directory.

Comment: Yeah, this worked @FrainBr33z3 , but the image occupied all the window and my text box disappear, any way to resize image?

Comment: Its doesn't worked @Mike-SMT same error, thanks

Comment: If you are getting the same error then your image file is not in the same working directory as your py file.

Comment: @LucasCruz The question is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273946/how-do-i-resize-an-image-using-pil-and-maintain-its-aspect-ratio)